How to visualize the mapping class group $\text{Mod}(S)$ from a topological perspective (from "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups" Farb & Margalit)
I am an undergrad student self-studying "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups" by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit. My (meager) background is in topology, mainly introductory point-set topology as well as some self-studied low-dimensional topology, and I'm finding it hard to visualize some of the more abstract geometric and algebraic structure without concrete examples or visual explanations.
In Section 2.1, the mapping class group $\text{Mod}(S)$ is defined to be $\text{Mod}(S) := \pi_0(\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S))$, where $\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S)$ is defined to be the group of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms $S \to S$ that restrict to the identity on $\partial S$.
I think there are a number of reasons why I am having trouble visualizing $\text{Mod}(S)$ for a space.

For one, I think I'm having trouble conceptualizing $\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S)$ without a definitive example of what this group looks like. I assume that it is infinite, so I can't quantify a finite set of elements to represent it, but any sort of definitive example would be quite helpful.
I'm also having difficulty visualizing $\pi_0(\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S))$, as thinking about groupings of functions and their topological properties is not something I'm used to.
Farb and Margalit also describe $\text{Mod}(S)$ to be the group of isotopy classes of elements of $\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S)$, where isotopies are required to fix the boundary point-wise. I think I understand this statement to ~some~ degree, however visualizing these isotopy classes is difficult for me, as well.
Lastly, $\text{Mod}(S)$ is also described as $\text{Mod}(S)  = \text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S)\;  / \; \text{Homeo}_0(S, \partial S)$, where $\text{Homeo}_0(S, \partial S)$ is defined to denote the connected component of the identity in $\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S)$. Again, I'm really just having trouble visualizing the different parts of this definition, mainly with what the connected component of an identity map looks like in general, and in $\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S)$.

I know this is quite a general question, and I apologize for how open-ended it is. I'm most comfortable working with low-dimensional topology at the moment, and so branching into geometric topology and geometric group theory has been challenging. Any sort of insight or intuition into $\text{Mod}(S)$ and/or $\text{Homeo}^+(S, \partial S)$, or any examples of these spaces/objects, would be more than appreciated. Also any wider intuition regarding geometric topology and group theory coming from a pure topology background is also welcome and appreciated.
Thanks so much in advance!
Edit: thanks to the comments below I now know that $\pi_0$ is the set of path components, instead of my (incorrect) understanding of it.

The expectation is that you know basic algebraic topology (homotopy, fundamental groups, covering spaces, homology) before reading this book. By the way, you are confusing $\pi_0$ and the fundamental group in your post.

$\pi_0$ is the set of path components, not the fundamental group.

@Randall thank you! This helps clear up my confusion somewhat

I'm not sure what you want in "visualizing" these hyper-abstract constructions.  You learn what they are by working with them.

@MoisheKohan thanks, but this is not a very helpful comment. Do you have any suggestions for how I can better think about these concepts with my current level of understanding?

I think Moishe's comment is that you are (potentially) reading this prematurely.  This material has LOTS of prerequisites, many of them deep, and you just can't expect for that not to matter.

@Randall this is a fair comment, and I understand your point. However, I'm not expecting to understand this textbook to a high degree, but I would like to be able to build somewhat of an intuition regarding the subjects discussed in it. I am wondering if there are any ways that I can better do this with my current background.

I recommend trying the chapter on mapping class groups in the book Office Hours with a Geometric Group Theorist, which is aimed at undergrads

@Chase Great! Thank you so much, I will definitely check this out!
